# Sort function Excel VB.Net

Tags: excel, vb.net, visual-studio, sorting

I use the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel libraries. What I do is enter alarms in an excel What I don't know how to do is that through vb.net I ordered the alarms by day and time, in such a way that it shows me the last alarm entered the first time. I cannot use macros, because I have already tried using a template and it gives me errors because on the other PC they use Open Office. Have you any solution occurs. Thank you so much for everything. All the best.

I attach the code for the insertion of the alarms.

```
Public Sub GuardarAlarmas()
    Dim fileTest As String = "C:\Users\DT SCADA\Desktop\Historicos\Alarmas\Año 2021\Alarmas 2021_11_noviembre.xlsm"
    Dim oExcel As Object
    Dim oBook As Workbook
    Dim oSheet As Worksheet
    oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    If File.Exists(fileTest) Then
        oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\DT SCADA\Desktop\Historicos\Alarmas\Año 2021\Alarmas 2021_11_noviembre.xlsm", ReadOnly:=False)
    End If
    oSheet = oExcel.Worksheets(1)
    'Cuento las líneas escritas en cada fila y le pongo un +6 porque empiezo en B6 y si quiero escribir en B7,B8 y viceversa necesito ponerle el +6
    Dim paco = oSheet.Range("A6").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 6
    Console.WriteLine(paco.ToString)
    'Aquí recojo el texto de estado, descripción, hora y día
    oSheet.Range("A" + paco.ToString).Value = Date.Today
    oSheet.Range("B" + paco.ToString).Value = TimeOfDay
    oSheet.Range("C" + paco.ToString).Value = "ACTIVA"
    oSheet.Range("D" + paco.ToString).Value = "DESCRIPCIÓN"
    'Aquí pongo un borde negro en el Excel
    Dim Range = oSheet.Range("A" + paco.ToString + ":D" + paco.ToString)
    Range.Borders.Color = Color.Black
    oSheet.UsedRange.Select()
    oSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear()
    oSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add(oSheet.UsedRange.Columns("A"), Excel.XlSortOn.xlSortOnValues, Excel.XlSortOrder.xlDescending, System.Type.Missing, Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal)
    Dim sort = oSheet.Sort
    sort.SetRange(oSheet.Range("A6:D1200"))
    sort.Header = Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlYes
    sort.MatchCase = False
    sort.Orientation = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSortOrientation.xlSortColumns
    sort.SortMethod = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSortMethod.xlPinYin
    sort.Apply()
    Try
        'Aquí uso el DisplayAlerts, para que directamente me confirme que deseo guardar el archivo.
        oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
        'Aquí guardo todos los datos introducidos
        oBook.SaveAs(Filename:="C:\Users\DT SCADA\Desktop\Historicos\Alarmas\Año 2021\Alarmas 2021_11_noviembre.xlsm", AccessMode:=3, ConflictResolution:=2, Local:=True)
        'Aquí pongo el DisplayAlerts a true, por si acaso este queda invalidado en toda la aplicación.
        oExcel.DisplayAlerts = True
        oBook.Close()
        oExcel.Quit()
    Catch
        'Si hubiese algún error en excel, mataría todos los procesos.
        Dim pListOfProcesses() As Process
        Dim pExcelProcess As System.Diagnostics.Process
        pListOfProcesses = pExcelProcess.GetProcesses
        For Each pExcelProcess In pListOfProcesses
            If pExcelProcess.ProcessName.ToUpper = "EXCEL" Then
                pExcelProcess.Kill()
            End If
        Next
    End Try
End Sub
```

[Download Excel Alarmas](https://www.mediafire.com/file/xlvo6dj12yrecmh/Alarmas+2021_11_noviembre.xlsm/file)

Comment: It's not really clear exactly what your trying to do here.  Is this table of data containing your alarms generated withing your vb.net project and then written to excel?  Perhaps you need to update your question with your best attempt to date.

Comment: Hello, I have attached a piece of code of how I do the insertion with the Microsoft Excel library in vb.net. So it would fix the question? Although what I'm really looking for is sorting by date and time. So I wrote a text explaining the problem.

Comment: Is this link - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/27a14605-32f6-4fe6-8e59-b5c40de1e6a7/sorting-columns-in-excel-c?forum=exceldev helpful to the question?

Comment: Yes, help me. But the sort fail me, you can prove my code. I upload code + link Excel ;)

Comment: Can someone test my code. Added the sort function to sort column B and C, but I can't get it to sort them. Column B and C are for sorting by Date and by Time. In theory the oldest date and highest time

Answer (score 0):

I leave you the solution, in the end I was able to make the computer as I wanted. Thank you very much everyone for the help. All the best.

```
  Public Sub GuardarAlarmas()
        'Creo la carpeta donde almacenare las alarmas de origen y la ruta del archivo del origen
        Dim MES = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM")
        Dim rutaDirectorioOrigen = FormMain.rutaHistoricoAlarmasOrigen + "Año " + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(rutaDirectorioOrigen)
        Dim rutaArchivoOrigen As String = rutaDirectorioOrigen + "\Alarmas " + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString + "_" + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString + "_" + MonthName(MES.ToUpper) + ".xlsm"
        'Creo la carpeta donde almacenaré las alarmas de destino y la ruta del archivo del destino
        Dim rutaDirectorioDestino = FormMain.rutaHistoricoAlarmasDestino + "Año " + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(rutaDirectorioDestino)
        Dim rutaArchivoDestino As String = rutaDirectorioDestino + "\Alarmas " + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString + "_" + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString + "_" + MonthName(MES.ToUpper) + ".xlsm"
        'Aqui declaro el objeto Aplicación excel, su libro y su hoja
        Dim oExcel As Object
        Dim oBook As Excel.Workbook
        Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
        'Inicializo la aplicacion Excel
        oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        'Si no existe el archivo de origen en excel, cojo la plantilla creada en excel y luego creo el Archivo de Ruta de Origen
        If Not File.Exists(rutaArchivoOrigen) Then
            oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FormMain.rutaHistoricoAlarmasOrigen + "PlantillaExcel.xlsm", ReadOnly:=False)
            oBook.SaveAs(Filename:=rutaArchivoOrigen, AccessMode:=3, ConflictResolution:=2, Local:=True)
            oBook.Close()
        End If
        'Si no existe el archivo de origen abro ese archivo
        If File.Exists(rutaArchivoOrigen) Then
            oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=rutaArchivoOrigen, ReadOnly:=False)
        End If
        'Elijo la primera hoja del excel
        oSheet = oExcel.Worksheets(1)
        'Cuento las líneas escritas en cada fila y le pongo un +6 porque empiezo en B6 y si quiero escribir en B7,B8 y viceversa necesito ponerle el +6
        Dim paco = oSheet.Range("B6").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1
        'Aquí recojo el texto de estado, descripción, hora y día
        Me.Label_Texto_Alarma.Text = arrayTexto(Me.Label_Numero_Alarma.Text)
        Dim estado = Me.Label_Estado_Alarma.Text
        Dim descrip = Me.Label_Texto_Alarma.Text
        Dim hora = TimeOfDay
        Dim dia = Date.Today.Day.ToString
        'Introduzco los datos de la alarma
        oSheet.Range("B" + paco.ToString).Value = dia
        oSheet.Range("C" + paco.ToString).Value = hora
        oSheet.Range("D" + paco.ToString).Value = estado
        oSheet.Range("E" + paco.ToString).Value = descrip
        'Si el estado es ACTIVA, el color será rojo. Si es inactiva será Verde y si es acusada será NARANJA
        If (estado.Equals("ACTIVA")) Then
            oSheet.Range("B" + paco.ToString + ":E" + paco.ToString).Font.Color = Color.Red
        End If
        If (estado.Equals("INACTIVA")) Then
            oSheet.Range("B" + paco.ToString + ":E" + paco.ToString).Font.Color = Color.Green
        End If
        If (estado.Equals("ACUSADA")) Then
            oSheet.Range("B" + paco.ToString + ":E" + paco.ToString).Font.Color = Color.Orange
        End If
        'Aquí pongo un borde negro en el Excel
        Dim rangos = oSheet.Range("B" + paco.ToString + ":E" + paco.ToString)
        rangos.Borders.Color = Color.Black
        oSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear()
        oSheet.UsedRange.Select()
        oSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add(oSheet.Range("B6:B1200"), Excel.XlSortOn.xlSortOnValues, Excel.XlSortOrder.xlDescending, System.Type.Missing, Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal)
        oSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add(oSheet.Range("C6:C1200"), Excel.XlSortOn.xlSortOnValues, Excel.XlSortOrder.xlDescending, System.Type.Missing, Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal)
        Dim sort = oSheet.Sort
        sort.SetRange(oSheet.Range("B6:E1200"))
        sort.Header = Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlYes
        sort.MatchCase = False
        sort.Orientation = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSortOrientation.xlSortColumns
        sort.SortMethod = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSortMethod.xlPinYin
        sort.Apply()
        Try
            'Aquí uso el DisplayAlerts, para que directamente me confirme que deseo guardar el archivo.
            oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
            'Aquí guardo todos los datos introducidos
            oBook.SaveAs(Filename:=rutaArchivoOrigen, AccessMode:=3, ConflictResolution:=2, Local:=True)
            oBook.SaveAs(Filename:=rutaArchivoDestino, AccessMode:=3, ConflictResolution:=2, Local:=True)
            'Aquí pongo el DisplayAlerts a true, por si acaso este queda invalidado en toda la aplicación.
            oExcel.DisplayAlerts = True
            oBook.Close()
            oExcel.Quit()
        Catch
            'Si hubiese algún error en excel, mataría todos los procesos.
            Dim pListOfProcesses() As Process
            Dim pExcelProcess As System.Diagnostics.Process
            pListOfProcesses = pExcelProcess.GetProcesses
            For Each pExcelProcess In pListOfProcesses
                If pExcelProcess.ProcessName.ToUpper = "EXCEL" Then
                    pExcelProcess.Kill()
                End If
            Next
        End Try
    End Sub
    Public WithEvents Label_Hora_Alarma As System.Windows.Forms.Label
End Class
```

Comment: Since your question has been solved, please consider [accepting your answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).